# Can I insert a image in the same line space as my header?

Tags: overleaf

I would like to insert a photo in the right side of the page but at the same direction of the header (name).
I inserted this code in my txt file and was able to put the photo in the right top corner, but it is up the header, which leaves too much blank space...

```
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=4cm, right]{jessphoto.jpg}
\end{figure}
```

Would it be possible to create a function in the cls file and then just call it in the txt file to do this?

This is part of my cls file configuration:

```
\ProvidesClass{resume}[2010/07/10 v0.9 Resume class]

\LoadClass[11pt,letterpaper]{article} % Font size and paper type

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\usepackage{array} % Required for boldface (\bf and \bfseries) tabular columns
\usepackage{ifthen} % Required for ifthenelse statements


\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADINGS COMMANDS: Commands for printing name and address
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\def \name#1{\def\@name{#1}} % Defines the \name command to set name
\def \@name {} % Sets \@name to empty by default


\def \addressSep {$\diamond$} % Set default address separator to a diamond

% One, two or three address lines can be specified 
\let \@addressone \relax
\let \@addresstwo \relax
\let \@addressthree \relax

% \address command can be used to set the first, second, and third address (last 2 optional)
\def \address #1{
  \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{
    \def \@addresstwo {#1}
  }{
  \@ifundefined{@addressthree}{
  \def \@addressthree {#1}
  }{
     \def \@addressone {#1}
  }}
}

% \printaddress is used to style an address line (given as input)
\def \printaddress #1{
  \begingroup
    \def \\ {\addressSep\ }
    \centerline{#1}
  \endgroup
  \par
  \addressskip
}

% \printname is used to print the name as a page header
\def \printname {
  \begingroup
    %\hfil{\MakeUppercase{\namesize\bf \@name}}\hfil
    \hfil{\namesize\bf \@name}\hfil
    \nameskip\break
  \endgroup
}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PRINT THE HEADING LINES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\let\ori@document=\document
\renewcommand{\document}{
  \ori@document  % Begin document
  \printname % Print the name specified with \name
  \printcvtitle
  \@ifundefined{@addressone}{}{ % Print the first address if specified
    \printaddress{\@addressone}}
  \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{}{ % Print the second address if specified
    \printaddress{\@addresstwo}}
     \@ifundefined{@addressthree}{}{ % Print the third address if specified
    \printaddress{\@addressthree}}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION FORMATTING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Defines the rSection environment for the large sections within the CV
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE FORMATTING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{ % 4 input arguments - company name, year(s) employed, job title and location
 {\bf #1} \hfill {#2} % Bold company name and date on the right
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{ % If the third argument is not specified, don't print the job title and location line
  \\
  {\em #3} \hfill {\em #4} % Italic job title and location
  }\smallskip
  \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em} % \cdot used for bullets, no indentation
   \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em} % Compress items in list together for aesthetics
  }{
  \end{list}
  \vspace{0.5em} % Some space after the list of bullet points
}

% The below commands define the whitespace after certain things in the document - they can be \smallskip, \medskip or \bigskip
\def\namesize{\huge} % Size of the name at the top of the document
\def\addressskip{\smallskip} % The space between the two address (or phone/email) lines
\def\sectionlineskip{\medskip} % The space above the horizontal line for each section 
\def\nameskip{\bigskip} % The space after your name at the top
\def\sectionskip{\medskip} % The space after the heading section
```

This is a part of my txt file:

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=RoyalBlue
    }

\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2667\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}
\newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}}
\name{your name} 
\address{your address} 
\address{ phone \\ email \\
\href{linkedIn link}{linkedIn label} } 

\begin{document}

%this is my attemptive to include the photo
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=4cm, right]{jessphoto.jpg}
\end{figure}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    ABOUT ME
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{rSection}{About Me}

Right here about you\vspace{7pt}


\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{rSection}{Work Experience}

\begin{rSubsection}{Company}{\date}{Position)}{}
\item description
\item description
\end{rSubsection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Projects And Seminars
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{rSection}{Projects}

\\{\bf Project Title}\\
description\vspace{7pt}
\\{\bf Project Title}\\
description\vspace{7pt}

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{rSection}{Education}

{\bf University} \hfill {\date} 
\\ Course \hfill 
\vspace{7pt}
{\bf University} \hfill {\date} 
\\ Course \hfill 
\vspace{7pt}
\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TECHNICAL SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Technical Skills}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{6ex}} l }
cathegory1 \ & number1, number2 and number3 \\
cathegory2 \ & number1, number2 and number3 \\
\vspace{7pt}
\end{tabular}
\end{rSection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. I believe it is compilable now. I am sorry for before, I am new at latex and posting questions.

Comment: remove `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` you just want `\includegraphics`

Comment: Thank you very much! By using `\raisebox{-.2\totalheight}[0pt][.3\totalheight]{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=4cm, right]{jessphoto.jpg}}` it works. Now I have a different problem :D

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best solution, but this works:

```
\raisebox{-.2\totalheight}[0pt][.3\totalheight]{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=4cm, right]{jessphoto.jpg}}
```